# How can I create a rule to move meeting requests to another calendar as they are received?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, rules, exchange-2003

I am using Outlook 2010 with Exchange 2003.  When meeting requests are received, Exchange automatically adds them individual calendars as "tentative".  This is what we would expect.

Is there a way I can personally create a rule within Outlook or something that can move these automatically created tentative appointments to another calendar within my own mailbox?

I had a nose around the rules but only found the option to move the meeting request itself.  Ideally it would be a rule that can run without Outlook being open, but I am at a loss with this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you've created a new calender by opening up Calender and selecting Folder -> new calender.

Then, in Outlooks rules and alerts, select the option 'which is a meeting invitation or update' and move it to your 'other' calender's folder. You may also have to add another rule about the subject including the word 'tentative' but this should do the trick.

Comment: I feel a bit stupid now for asking, being an "IT professional".  Tested and it appears to work perfectly.  Thanks muchly.